# How do I know if a Facebook Status/Photo/Link is Private?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When I'm getting a status/link/photo from facebook API, how do I know if it has been shared with the public or if it's a private post?

Also - is there a way to query only public posts?

I'm currently using the `/<username>/status` `/<username>/links` `/<username>/photos` endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With the graph api

From the 3 endpoints you are using, only one gives you access to the privacy settings the `/<username>/links`. It returns a privacy object, something like this:

```
{
  "id": "USER_FB_ID", 
  "links": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "ID_OF_THE_POST", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Fábio Antunes", 
          "id": "USER_FB_ID"
        }, 
        "message": "Check this awesome link", 
        "privacy": {
          "description": "Friends; Except: Restricted", 
          "value": "ALL_FRIENDS", 
          "allow": "", 
          "deny": "", 
          "networks": "", 
          "friends": ""
        },
(etc....)
```

### With FQL

To solve your problem you could use **FQL** this way you can get the 3 endpoints that have public access.

For the **links** you can use this query:

```
Select link_id,owner_comment, title, url, privacy FROM link WHERE owner = me() AND privacy.value='EVERYONE'
```

*note: check the [link table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link/) to see if there are any fields that you may want to add to this query*

Since the **links table** from the 3 endpoints is the only with privacy settings structure to get the user photos and statuses that are public you will have to use the [privacy table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy/).

To get all the users public photos I made 2 joins, first I'm getting the user photos, then I want the privacy settings of the photos that are available to everyone and then I select the photos that have the privacy settings public:

```
SELECT caption,src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT id FROM privacy WHERE value='EVERYONE' AND object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo WHERE owner=me()))
```

*note: check the [photo table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/) to see if there are any fields that you may want to add to this query*

To get the public statuses it's the same process for the photos, two joins:

```
SELECT status_id , message, place_id  FROM status WHERE status_id IN (SELECT id FROM privacy WHERE value='EVERYONE' AND object_id IN (SELECT status_id FROM status WHERE uid=me()))
```

*note: check the [status table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/) to see if there are any fields that you may want to add to this query*